# What is the で part in ではありません？

Tags: grammar, particles, verbs, negation, nouns

Ok, this might be more complicated or less complicated than I'm making it out to be but I'm assuming this question will be made up of two unrelated components but I can't figure it out so I'm shooting my shot here. I also don't know how exactly to word what I'm asking.

I'm using Rosetta Stone as a jumping-off point for learning Japanese, frankly, I am not too pleased with how it "teaches", but my work is paying for it so here I am. My question may be caused by the way they format but I can't figure out what I need to google to get an answer.

In the grammar module of lesson three they highlight the new concept they're teaching. So the way they format it is:

私は医者**ではありません**
and
私は教師**です**

Now, I know that the です part is to indicate politeness, is the で in ではありません there for the same reason? Is it there just to make ありません polite?

AND THEN! In the grammar module for lesson two they introduced いません, it's preceded by て, is that because it's attached to the verb before it? (I know it can also be で with some verbs, which is where I think my confusion overall stems from, i.e. the で from my first question and the て／で here have different functions).

Is で a part of ありません, or is it there because it's following a noun? Why is it there? And on that note, correct me if I'm wrong, but contextually I'm assuming いません is for actions and ありません is for things not performing actions. Context: The ありません was used in the sentence, "I am not a doctor", and the いません was used in the sentence, "They are not sleeping".

Am I even headed vaguely in the right direction or am I completely misunderstanding everything?

*(and before anyone says anything about Rosetta Stone being good or bad, I'm aware, it's just an extra tool I am using alongside other resources mostly for the kanji.)*

Comment: My personal suggestion if you have just started learning Japanese is to learn that ではありません / じゃありません / ではない / じゃない are just the negative ("isn't") counterpart of です / だ ("is") and treat them as indivisible units. In reality it's far more complex than that, but it's better to come back to this topic once you have delved more into Japanese and have a grasp of how basic sentences work. You already noticed there seem to be many different parts ( で, は, ありません) being combined and it's only natural to try to wrap your head around it. But sometimes adquisition is more important than understanding.

Comment: @jarmanso7 thank you! I'll come back to this later then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good on you for giving Japanese a go!

Ya, Japanese and English are very different, structurally, and some of what's happening in Japanese makes more sense if you know some of the history (well, English has those bits too, as do most languages, for that matter ), so I'll give you short answers, and then a fuller explanation.

## The short of it

> *... is the で in ではありません there for the same reason? Is it there just to make ありません polite?*

No.  The で in ではありません is a separate word.  The politeness comes from the ません ending on ありません.

> *Is で a part of ありません?*

No, see above.

> *... or is it there because it's following a noun?* Why is it there?

Yes.  More on that in the longer explanation below.

> *And on that note, correct me if I'm wrong, but contextually I'm assuming いません is for actions and ありません is for things not performing actions.*

Broadly speaking, yes, this is a good initial understanding.

> *Am I even headed vaguely in the right direction or am I completely misunderstanding everything?*

Sounds like you've got a good start, for the most part.

## The long of it

To really explain what's going on takes some doing.  Let's dive in.

### Part 1: The で in ではありません

> > 私は医者ではありません and 私は教師です
>
> *Now, I know that the です part is to indicate politeness, is the で in ではありません there for the same reason? Is it there just to make ありません polite?*

The で is not there *"just to make ありません polite"*.  :)  The ます (positive) and ません (negative) verb endings are the polite parts here.

The で in ではありません (and in the so-called "plain form" ではない, also seen as contracted form じゃない) is, technically speaking, best thought of as the *conjunctive form* ("`[VERB]`, *and* `[whatever comes next]`") of the modern *copula* ("to be" verb).  The polite form of the copula is です, and the plain form is だ.

The modern だ・です copula in Japanese is a synthetic word -- it was basically cobbled together from disparate dialectal variations in the late 1800s as part of the nation-building efforts during the Meiji period.  Due in part to this synthetic origin, the modern copula is irregular, and it doesn't conjugate fully.  While other verbs have explicit negative forms (like plain する has しない, and polite します has しません), the copula だ・です doesn't have a negative, per se -- instead, we have to use the conjunctive form of the copula (this で) and then add the otherwise-distinct word ない ("there isn't; not", which inflects like any other *-i* adjective) for the plain form, or ありません ("there isn't; not") for the polite form.

#### What is that は doing there?

When we negate a statement (when we say that X isn't Y), we are often saying that X isn't Y *in contrast to* what X actually is.  Due to this underlying contrastive nuance, in Japanese, we often add the particle は into this mix.  This は particle is usually explained in introductory grammars as the particle used to mark the topic of a statement, and it is also used to introduce a contrast.  So instead of just で + ない or ありません, we get で + は + ない・ありません.

#### A note about the copula

Above, I describe だ・です as the "modern copula".  In older stages of the Japanese language, the main copula (again, that's the "to be" verb) was ある・あります -- or, classically speaking, あり.  Nowadays, ある・あります is usually used to mean "there is something (in a place, by a person, etc.)", expressing the existence of something in a specific context, rather than just "to be / is".  That said, the original very basic "to be" copular meaning still shows up to some extent in modern Japanese, such as in the ありません part ("is not") of polite-form ではありません.

I wrote a longer post explaining だ・です and its relationship to あり over [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62645/%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99-what-is-it-really-is-my-analysis-correct/62647#62647), in answer to the question, [*"「です」, what is it really? Is my analysis correct?"*](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62645/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-what-is-it-really-is-my-analysis-correct/)

> *Is で a part of ありません, or is it there because it's following a noun? Why is it there?*

Put simply:

- No, the で is not part of ありません: this で is a separate verb, the modern copula だ (plain form) and です (polite form), in the conjunctive conjugation.
- Yes, it is there because it is following a noun.  To say that "X is Y", that one noun (or noun phrase) **is** another noun (or noun phrase), you need the copula to equate the two.  To negate the copula, you need to conjugate the copula into the conjunctive form, and then add the separate piece ない (plain form) or ありません (polite form).

### Part 2: ～て・～で + いません

The ～て ending for verbs is the so-called *conjunctive form*, much like we saw above with で as the *conjunctive form* for the copula だ・です.

In English, your basic conjunction is "and" -- *"A, **and** B..."*

In Japanese, the *-te* form is the main conjunction for verbs.

You ask about verbs ending in ～で as well.  This is ultimately a shift from ～て due to a kind of phonetic contraction.

- Historically, older forms of Japanese were more regular than the modern language, and the conjunctive forms for all verbs ended in ～て.  You would convert verb into the *-te* form by adding this as a suffix to the verb base conjugated as the so-called 連用形【れんようけい】 -- literally the 連【れん】 "attaches, connects to" + 用【よう】 "inflecting" (short for 用言【ようげん】, "inflecting word")  + 形【けい】 "form", or the "form for connecting to an inflecting word" (suffixes like conjunctive ～て and polite ～ます are historically treated as inflecting words).  In modern educational materials written in English about the Japanese language, this is often introduced as the "*masu* stem", since this is the form of the verb base used to add the ～ます stem indicating polite register.  The *masu* stem for よむ ("to read") is よみ～, so in older Japanese, the conjunctive form of よむ ("to read") was よみて.  Likewise, およぐ ("to swim") became およぎ～, and the conjunctive form was およぎて.
- Due to sound shifts over time, those verbs where the *masu* stem ends in *-i*, **and** where the preceding consonant is //m//, //b//, //n//, or //g//, the *-i* vowel [elided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) (dropped out), and the nasality of the consonant abbreviated to just the ん sound and caused the following *-te* suffix to voice to *-de* instead.
  So よみて or *yomite* shifted to something like *yomte*, then to *yonde*.  And およぎて or *oyogite* shifted to something like *oyogte*, then to *oyonde*.  Etc., etc.
- Note that **this ～で after verb stems is *not* the same thing as the copular で.**
  Although they both serve a similar grammatical function (both indicate a conjunction, "this AND that"), and although they both derive in part from the same original piece (see Old Japanese completion-aspect suffix つ if you're really interested), the copular で and the verb suffix ～で are different things.

### Part 3: いません vs. ありません

> *...I'm assuming いません is for actions and ありません is for things not performing actions. Context: The ありません was used in the sentence, "I am not a doctor", and the いません was used in the sentence, "They are not sleeping".*

Broadly, this is correct -- います (positive) and いません (negative) are used after the conjunctive ～て form of a non-copular verb describing an action or state, and あります (positive) and ありません (negative) are used after the conjunctive で form of the copula describing existence.

There are also statements where a noun is followed by the topic particle は or the subject particle が, and then either of these verbs.  This is used to state that something simply exists, that "there is XYZ", rather than to state that one thing is another thing.

→ It's important to note that, in modern Japanese, there's the wrinkle that いる・います is used for describing the existence of a person or other animate objects capable of intent (like cats or dogs or hamsters), while ある・あります is used for describing the existence of inanimate objects incapable of intent (like books or pillows or houses).

Whether you use で or は・が changes the meanings too.

A couple examples might help.

- ✔ 本【ほん】があります。 → "**There is** a book." → describes the existence of a book.
- ✖ 本【ほん】がいます。 → *"**There is** a book." → bad grammar, since a book is inanimate and cannot have intent.  Listeners will probably be able to understand this, but will find it weird: this makes it sound like the book has animacy.
- ✔ 本【ほん】であります。 → "[It] **is** a book." → describes the existence of "it" as a book.
- ✖ 本【ほん】でいます。 → *"[It] **is** a book." → bad grammar, since the "it" that is a book is inanimate and cannot have intent.  Listeners will probably be able to understand this, but will find it weird.  If the implied topic in this context is a person, this sentence might be understandable as "[the unstated person] **is being** a book", which is a weird statement, but maybe a bit better grammatically?

---

I hope the above helps.  If you find anything confusing, please comment and I can try to address any remaining question marks.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain everything so thoroughly! This is amazing and more informative than I expected (especially the historical context). You've cleared up a lot of confusion for me, I appreciate this so much :^)

Comment: "本であります" sounds so odd. I'd expect either "本です" or "本でございます"

Comment: Re 「In older stages of the Japanese language, the main copula (again, that's the "to be" verb) was ある・あります -- or, classically speaking, あり. 」: In EMJ, main copula ("to be NOUN") was *nari* / *naru* (or uncontracted *ni ari* / *ni aru*, which would be also required when a focus particle is inside, e.g. *ni mo ari*), while *ari* / *aru* was existential verb ("to be (somewhere), to exist") (but then *ari* / *aru* was used for both inanimate and animate subjects, while in modern Japanese using *aru* for animate subjects seems to be literary or archaic).

Comment: Re 「So よみて or *yomite* shifted to something like *yomte*, then to *yonde*. And およぎて or *oyogite* shifted to something like *oyogte*, then to *oyonde*.」:  There were never forms *oyogte*, *oyonde* :) . Voicing of *t* probably occurred earlier (possibly as result of shifting place of nasalization (nasalization was cause of voicing since pre-Old Japanese, and voiced *b*, *d*, *z*, *g* were prenasalized)), and *-m-* / *-b-* verbs had 2 variants: *yomite* → *yoĩde* / *yonde* → *yoũde* / *yonde* → *yōde* / *yonde* (variant *yōde* died out later); *oyogite* → *oyoĩde* → *oyoide*.

Comment: Regarding reference to completion-aspect suffix つ, Alexander Vovin (2020) argued that *-te* suffix is unrelated to *-tu* perfective (since e.g. *-tete*, i.e. perfective + conjunctive, is attested). Bjarke Frellesvig (2010) did not suggest that *-te* suffix is related to *-tu* perfective (and he dropped his earlier (2001) theory that *-te* suffix is related to *tə* → *to* copula).

Comment: @Ethir You should also learn term [suppletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion). While *de aru* → *de arimasu* is regular polite conjugation, and *de aru* → *dea* → *da* is some irregular historical contraction of this verb, *desu* is most likely etymologically unrelated to *de aru*, and comes from *desɔː* ([で候](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/で候)), contraction of *de sɔːrɔː* (modernized pronunciation would be *de soːrou*), where *sɔːrɔː* (modernized [候う](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/候う)) developed ultimately from *samorapu* (modern [侍う](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/侍う)).

Comment: @Ethir Usage of *nai* as negative form of *aru* in modern Japanese is another example of suppletion. In Old Japanese and Early Middle Japanese, where *-(a)zu* / *-(a)nu* was negative suffix, verb *ari* / *aru* had regularly formed negative *arazu* / *aranu*.

Comment: @Arfrever, bear in mind that this was intended as a primer -- not an exhaustive explication of all details.    For example, re: _yogte_ and _yomte_, these are approximations—hence my wording of "something like". Re: です origins, the evidence for でそうろう seems lacking and limited in context, as compared to でございます: see the comments on my answer post at https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62645/%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99-what-is-it-really-is-my-analysis-correct/62647#62647.

Comment: @Arfrever, Interesting about _-tete_, that's the first I've heard of that particular combination. FWIW, monolingual JA sources describe て as the 連用形 of つ; I'm curious how Vovin and Frellesvig square that. I don't suppose you have any titles or links to papers?  The `NAME (YEAR)` format might be well and good for academic citations, but it means bupkus to most of the rest of us, and it's even more obtuse for authors who have more than one publication a year. 

Comment: @Arfrever, re: てて, when is that attested, and is it unambiguously `[連用形 of つ]` + `[conjunctive て]`? Only, there's Middle Japanese てて cited to the 1600s as a vowel shift from とて, as described at https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A6-576427.

Comment: "The で in ではありません (and in the so-called "plain form" ではない, also seen as contracted form じゃない) is, technically speaking, best thought of as the conjunctive form..." what exactly is the basis for analyzing it this way, rather than as just the case particle で (especially seeing as it follows a noun in the examples)? Or is this an analysis which unifies those two things by considering the i-stem sufficiently "noun-like", or something like that?

Comment: @Arfrever "Usage of nai as negative form of aru in modern Japanese is another example of suppletion." - any thoughts on why this suppletion took place, rather than ある forming regular あらない?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, arguably, the で's that aren't verb suffixes are the same thing: if one looks at derivation, whether you call it a case particle or the conjunctive of the copula, this comes from case particle に + conjunctive て. The historical phonological changes that produced verb-suffix で make it clear that this is not the same as the で that comes after nouns of after verbs in the 終止形 / predicative form.

Comment: ... Wait, when does で come after a verb in 終止形? Anyway, what I'm really confused by is the claim that で in である is already copulative, i.e. a conjunctive form of だ, given that だ is already contracting である. Isn't that... recursive? Why would I express "copula-is <noun> -and ある", when I could just express "copula-is <noun>"? My model has been that ordinary particle-で converts ある "to exist" into a copula, by explaining *how* the subject exists: e.g. to be a cat is to exist as a cat; to be walking is to exist walking-ly.

Comment: (But yes, I get the idea that verb-suffix で is a sound shift from verb-suffix = conjunctive て, i.e. there is no intermediary に.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149996/discussion-between-eirikr-utlendi-and-arfrever).